# ALT attribute in menu images

Tags: images, menus

I have a few missing attributes in my WP Theme.

I found images in header.php in example:

```
class="articles"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/topmenu/ikona_artykuly.png" />
```

`ikona_artykuly.png` has missing attribute.

Can I add alt attribute in this place?

```
class="articles"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/topmenu/ikona_artykuly.png" alt="Artykuly" />
```

Will it be ok, or this is not the right place to add alt attribute?

Can you help?

Regards,
Marceli

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the alt attribute. But there is a catch.

**When the theme is updated, all your changes or modification to the theme will be lost.**

It is recommended to make those changes in the child theme. You can learn more about WordPress child theme [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)